# Add an application title, and an image, to Win8's startup splash screen

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, splash-screen

I work at one of those benighted companies that don't realize the benefits of living entirely within the MS world. (My bosses are so deluded by social media group-think they actual make us use PyQt4, but that's neither here nor there...;)

So, in terms of saving me a lot of bookyuck, how does an app that is NOT generated by Visual Studio put all of ...

- a rotating picture
- a string of text

... into MS's vaunted Win8 start splash screen?

I think it has something to do with writing a package.appxmanifest, and putting some splashscreen.jpg goodness inside that. Then I send the manifest to the splash screen by ... what? Registering it? Installing it with the right-click context menu?

What's the shortest path to this simple task?

Answer (score 0):

See [Desktop App tiles on the Start Screen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj673981%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but it's not what you were hoping for.

[Obly Tile](http://winempyrean.net/obly-tile/) looks interesting, but I suspect that's something they do ex post facto to put a shell around a desktop app that's already installed, but perhaps that's sufficient for your needs?

Comment: OblyTile it is. one can merely read the file locations it will use, and upload the "latest representative" image to that file location from our actual app. Which remains gleefully metro-free.